# VS Code Python auto Import

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am missing the auto import feature in VS Code for Python development. I have the official Python plugin installed which should have solved this. My python directory has `__init__.py` and when I open the same project on PyCharm I get import suggestion but not on VS Code.

The option `Auto Import:Auto Complete` is also checked both on User and Workspace level on my `Settings.py` am I missing something ?

I tried the [importmagic plugin too](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brainfit.vscode-importmagic) but did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto imports are not supporting by the Python extension at the moment (you may have turned it on for another language like TypeScript). You can upvote the [issue tracking this feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21) to help show that you would like to see it implemented.